Zap proxy converts Http requests to Https
I need to pass the trafic of my Rest-Assured tests to the Zap proxy (version 2.14.0). I have configured the zap proxy as below picture and it works well for the Https requests:

However when i try to send a HTTP request, the zap proxy changes the protocol to HTTPS again and as a result the request fails.and in the log i can see the following:
<html>
  <body>Redirecting to https://my-service.com/myPath</body>
</html>

Do you know, how can i prevent ZAP to change the protocol ?

Turn off the ZAP HUD - thats the component that has to convert HTTP to HTTPS.
If you run ZAP in command line or daemon mode then the HUD will not be enabled by default.

Thanks. The problem fixed after i disabled the ZAP HUD from Tool-> Options -> HUD -> Uncheck "Enable when using ZAP desktop"
